# Calculating Euler's constant with OCaml

Tags: scheme, ocaml, divide-by-zero, eulers-number

I started learning OCaml today. I already knew Scheme so I thought it would be good to try to translate some example Scheme programs to ML. I have some code below for calculating Euler's number which works, but it does not work in OCaml. I get this error: `Exception: Division_by_zero.` I think that this might be a problem with mixing floats and ints somewhere. I have not been able to figure out how to set breakpoints for functions with `ocamldebug`. Can anyone identify where my mistake is happening? Thank you.

```lisp
(define (factorial n)
    (if (zero? n) 1 (* n (factorial (sub1 n)))))

(define (find-e accuracy sum)
    (if (zero? accuracy) (add1 sum)
        (find-e (sub1 accuracy) (+ sum (/ 1 (factorial accuracy))))))

(display (format "~f" (find-e 100 0)))
```

```ml
let rec factorial n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * factorial (n - 1) ;;

let rec find_e accuracy sum =
    if accuracy == 0
        then (sum + 1)
        else find_e (accuracy - 1) (sum + (1 / factorial accuracy)) ;;

let result = find_e 100 0 ;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, scheme has a "numerical tower" that tries to keep you from losing accuracy in numeric computations.

OCaml doesn't have any fancy automatic handling of numbers. Your code is using type `int`, which is a fixed size integer (31 or 63 bits in the usual implementations). Thus, your expression `1 / factorial accuracy` will be 0 in almost all cases and values for `factorial accuracy` will be unrepresentable for all but the smallest values. The value of `factorial 100` will be `0` because it is a multiple of 2^63:

```
# let rec fact n = if n < 2 then 1 else n * fact (n - 1);;
val fact : int -> int = <fun>
# fact 100;;
- : int = 0
```

There are no floats in your code, and hence there couldn't possibly be any mixing. But OCaml doesn't allow mixing in the first place. It's a strongly typed language where `int` and `float` are two different types.

Here is your code converted to use floats:

```
let rec factorial n =
    if n = 0.0 then 1.0 else n *. factorial (n -. 1.0) 

let rec find_e accuracy sum =
    if accuracy = 0.0 then
        sum +. 1.0
    else
        find_e (accuracy -. 1.0) (sum +. 1.0 /. factorial accuracy)

let result = find_e 100.0 0.0
```

If I copy/paste this into the OCaml REPL (also known as "toplevel") I see this:

```
val factorial : float -> float = <fun>
val find_e : float -> float -> float = <fun>
val result : float = 2.71828182845904509
```

As a side comment, the equality comparison operator in OCaml is `=`. Don't use `==` for comparisons. It's a completely different operator:

```
# 1.0 == 1.0;;
- : bool = false
```

Comment: do you mean that I should change each instance of `int` to `float`?

Comment: This will work better, but 100 factorial isn't representable as a float either. You would also need to change your operators to be ones that work with float. I don't think this is homework :-) so I'll write up a version that uses float.

Comment: Does that mean that there are alternative operators just for floats?

Comment: Yes, OCaml is strongly typed. A given function (like `+`) works only with values of one type (`int` in this case). The operator for adding floats is `+.` (with trailing period or decimal point).

Comment: (I can't edit my comment above, but 100 factorial can actually be represented pretty well as a float. OCaml floats (which are actually double precision) can represent a wider range than I was thinking.)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is meant as a complement to the currently accepted one.

Since factorials are integer values, it is somewhat unfortunate to use floats to represent the computation, as it introduces a loss of precision for large enough values. Scheme and Lisp have a transparent support for bignums and ratios, but OCaml has a library for that.

```
opam install zarith
```

Then in your ocaml  toplevel:

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "zarith";;
/home/user/.opam/4.11.0/lib/zarith: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/4.11.0/lib/zarith/zarith.cma: loaded
```

There are two main modules, Z and Q (integers and rationals), as well as a compatibility module for an older big integers module. You probably want to have a look at the documentation: https://antoinemine.github.io/Zarith/doc/latest/Z.html

The library define its own type for integers:

```
# Z.of_int(3);;
- : Z.t = <abstr>
```

If you install the pretty-printer:

```
# #install_printer Z.pp_print;;
# Z.of_int(3);;
- : Z.t = 3
```

Likewise, the Q module can help when computing fractions. You probably can implement an equivalent version of your code in OCaml that way.